# Sprites of SKSpriteNode are blurred only on the iPhone 7 Plus real machine

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a game app with SpriteKit and latest Xcode.
I want to display single color sprites in pixel perfect.
I tried the following code.

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.gray, size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
sprite.texture?.filteringMode = .nearest
addChild(sprite)
```

In most cases, it was ideally displayed.
(Specifically, it is all iOS simulators, real machine of iPhone 6s, iPod touch, iPad.)
However, in iPhone 7 Plus real machine, it is blurred like the image below.

[image]

I understand that it is impossible to display pixel perfect because the image of 1242 x 2208 pixels is downsampled to 1080 x 1920 pixels in iPhone Plus series.
But the screenshot should be pixel perfect because It get 1242 x 2208 pixels before downsampling.
I can not try it because I do not have it, but I think it will be the same result on the iPhone 6 Plus real machine and iPhone 6s Plus real machine.

Is there a way to solve this?

My English is not good.
Thank you.

---

I tried the idea of @Knight0fDragon.
I arranged sprites with a height of 0.666667 in 20 senses.
I tried SKView size at 414 x 736 and 360 x 640.
As a result, although it is not pixel perfect, it got much better.
However, the size of the screenshot is still 1242 x 2208 pixel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cadgp.png

Comment: Good question! This is something I've been wondering about, too. Some frameworks have the ability to access the 1920x1080 resolution directly, without scaling. I'm surprised SpriteKit isn't one of them.

Comment: Are you sure you are not in an aspect fill scale mode?  What is the size of your scene also

Comment: @Confused apple OS does not allow you to access the 1920x1080 directly while maintaining retina style development.  You would have to get rid of all the retina and point systems in place and write directly to the GPU to achieve it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The size of scene is (414.0, 736.0) on the iPhone 7 Plus.  I used `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` to set size. I tried all of scale mode (.aspectFill, .aspectFit, .Fill, .resizeFill). But the results were all the same.

Comment: @Confused I wonder that the screenshot of the simulator is pixel perfect, but the screenshot of the real machine is blurred.

Comment: The simulator is ONLY a tool for rapid development testing. It's not accurate in many ways, and only a simulator, not a realistic simulator. I never use it. To build to device is fast enough, for me. Anything the simulator does that's dissimilar to the device... well, it's just a simulator. Not the real thing. @hnxmb

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Both OpenGL and Metal allow writing applications to a window that's a pure 1920x1080, without scaling.

Comment: How are you taking the screen shot? The built in hardware and home would only give you a 1080 image I thought

@Confused, OpenGL and Metal are how you write directly to the GPU,

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I take by pressing the home button and the power button at the same time. And a screen shot of 1242 x 2208 pixels will be saved.

Comment: Hmm it may have to do with SKViiew,  I turned of scaling on the view, I centered the content mode, and I am getting a black border around my game

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is the black border the width of the difference between 1920x1080 and 2208x1242?

Comment: Yup, I was correct.  I made a scene 360x640  (which is 1080x1920 @3x) and I was able to get pixel perfect on a screenshot.  So what is happening is the context is 1080x1920, that gets scaled to 1242x2208, then back to 1080x1920 again.  This would provide the best quality on screen since it is attempting to undo the scaling done by the auto scaling. Looks like Apple went with having quality on screen over quality on a screen shot, Of course, that now messes with resizeFill, since it should be resizing to 1080

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if you scale something from 1080x1920 to 1242x2208, and then back to 1080x1920, you're going to get blurring during the upscaling that won't go away during the downscaling.

Comment: @Confused depends on the scale mode,  nearest neighbor should return it to almost exactly the same if it is done correctly

Comment: @Knight0fDragon "almost" being the key word. There will be blurring, and nothing can get rid of that because the upscale from 1080x1920 to 1242x2208 introduces a slight edge blur that's impossible to get rid of once it's introduced.

Comment: nearest neighbor doesnt intruduce bluring, because it is an exact copy of it's neighboring pixel

Comment: Nearest neighbour only works correctly if the scaling operation results in there being a doubling in the number of pixels available in both axis. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: no you get a distorted image when you scale up, but when you scale back down it removes all the added pixels, you just cant use the same exact formula for scaling up and down,  for scaling up you need to round down, when scaling down you round up.  For example,  I have 2 pixels next to each other, black and white.  I scale up by 150%.  I now have BBW because I rounded down.  now I want to scale down by 66% (66 is the inverse of 150  2/3 vs 3/2) I get back to BW because I rounded up, meaning I replace the middle black pixel with the white pixel

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've added a gridded image in an "answer" below so you can test your theory. I think you'll find the distortion becomes a problem with a messy little scale like 1080x1920 to 1242x2208

Comment: @Knight0fDragon and OP hnxmb, let me know if there's other images and grids/patterns you'd like or need to test.

Comment: @Confused Thank you very much. I'd like to use a 2px width line for the UI. When I tried the idea of Knight0fDragon, it is not pixel perfect but it has improved considerably. I added the appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `SKShapeNode` which has an `.isAntialiased` field (set this to false).

You can then use the shape node to draw lines wherever you want according to math, and it should be pixel-perfect and crisp.

If you have to have them as sprites, then you can convert the ShapeNode to a texture, and hope it doesn't lose any quality:

Here's a sampling I made that converts a labelNode to a texture:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ea86cf6a32bdd79376cc2a4f4d5a151

The only other idea I can think of is using `.usesMipMaps` for your texture.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pixel perfect 1080 by 1920 image to work with for anyone keen to see if they can solve this problem.

[image]

Nearest Neighbor to 1242:

[image]

Nearest Neighbor back to 1080:

[image]

Comment: I added nearest neighbor scaled up, then back down.  I overlayed in GIMP,  my eyes are not detecting a change

Comment: I think GIMP and Photoshop might handle this correctly. The question is... does the iPhone and iOS?

Comment: I dont know,  I would hope it is using nearest neighbor because it is the tastest method,  I cant find anyway to actually select what method it picks

Comment: I also do not have a camera with a high enough MP count and manual focus to take a proper photo of the screen

Comment: Judging from the nature of the OP's question and his demonstrations, I think there is a problem with how SK handles scaling on the big iPhones. Probably because they're so determined to hype the 1x, 2x, 3x artwork pipeline that's important to promoting SpriteKit. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: well he may just have a false positive because he is using the screen shot as his basis,  if he correctly sets the size of the scene, he may see the results on the screen to be correct (I had to use an aspect fill scale mode so that the scene size does not get butchered)